# XML Namespace prefix only on root

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating an XML document using the Task Factory XML Output Destination task though the output needs some tweaking and I can't seem to find a way to do this within the task so figured I would be able to do this via the script component with C#.

This is the XML I am working with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CSDS xmlns="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CSDS-v1-0">
  <CYP000>
    <C000010>1.0</C000010>
  </CYP000>
</CSDS>
```

And I need to change the XML to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CSDS:CSDS xmlns:CSDS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CSDS-v1-0">
  <CYP000>
    <C000010>1.0</C000010>
  </CYP000>
</CSDS>
```

I have tried creating a new XDocument declaring the namespace and adding the source elements in but this adds the namespace to all elements.

```
string xmlFile = @"C:\Temp\csds.xml";
string newXmlFile = @"C:\Temp\csds-new.xml";

XDocument sourceXml = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CSDS-v1-0";
XDocument newXml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
XElement newRoot = new XElement(ns + "CSDS",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "CSDS", ns.NamespaceName));

newRoot.Add(sourceXml.Root.Elements());
newRoot.Save(newXmlFile);
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CSDS:CSDS xmlns:CSDS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CSDS-v1-0">
  <CSDS:CYP000>
    <CSDS:C000010>1.0</CSDS:C000010>
  </CSDS:CYP000>
</CSDS:CSDS>
```

Comment: Well your desired output changes the namespace of the `CYP000` and `C00010` elements to the empty namespace. If you make that change in the XDocument, it should work. Please provide a [mcve], which will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @ChrFin yes made a mistake with the example there should be a closing tag for `CYP000`

Comment: Please fix the example and also add the code you have now which does also add the namespace to the inner nodes.

Comment: @ChrFin Updated my question

Comment: @ChrFin the source xml namespace is declared `xmlns="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CSDS-v1-0"` and not `xmlns:CSDS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CSDS-v1-0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that doing the following after loading my file works along with the rest of my code:

```
foreach (var descendants in sourceXml.Root.Descendants())
     descendants.Name = descendants.Name.LocalName;
```